# MVC - Generating multiple PDFs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, document

I am using the following code for generating a `PDF` file.

It is working good, but now i want to generate `4 PDF's` at the same time.

I tried by again initiating `Document` & repeating the whole code for generating 2nd PDF report, But it generates only 1 PDF.

```
            var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);

            // Create a new PdfWrite object, writing the output to a MemoryStream
            var output = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

            // Open the Document for writing
            document.Open();

            string contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Original.html"));

            var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(contents), null);
            foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements)
                     document.Add(htmlElement as IElement);    

           document.Close();

           Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
           Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=Receipt-{0}.pdf", "Report"));
           Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray());

           return View();
```

How to generate multiple PDF's?

Answer (score 3):

You are outputting the bytes as a response, so you would never be able of generating 2 different files in one response. Only one response per request.
If you want the user to download 2 different PDFs at the same time you could call the controller using javascript from the view.

Comment: give me as correct answer please! i am desesperated for points haha